# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL sever

Tags: java, mysql

im getting this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FIRSTIP='83.242.83.190',IP='83.242.83.190',MUTE='0',MU' at line 1
```

my code:

```
        sb.append("INSERT INTO `TOOLS_USERS` VALUES(");
    sb.append("'%name%',");
    sb.append("'%firstip%',");
    sb.append("'%ip%',");
    sb.append("%mute%,");
    sb.append("%mutereason%,");
    sb.append("TIME=%time%,");
    sb.append(") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ");
    sb.append("FIRSTIP='%firstip%',");
    sb.append("IP='%ip%',");
    sb.append("MUTE=%mute%,");
    sb.append("MUTEREASON=%mutereason%;");
```

tried '%mutereason%'; but still didn't work and the same error :v
anyone ideas? : D

Comment: You have an errant comma

Comment: There's an extra comma after `TIME=%time%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sb.append("INSERT INTO `TOOLS_USERS` VALUES(");
sb.append("'%name%',");
sb.append("'%firstip%',");
sb.append("'%ip%',");
sb.append("%mute%,");
sb.append("%mutereason%,");
sb.append("TIME=%time%**,**"); <- The error is the following comma. Try to erase it and compile again.
sb.append(") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ");
sb.append("FIRSTIP='%firstip%',");
sb.append("IP='%ip%',");
sb.append("MUTE=%mute%,");
sb.append("MUTEREASON=%mutereason%;");
```

Code should look similar to this:

```
sb.append("INSERT INTO `TOOLS_USERS` VALUES(");
sb.append("'%name%',");
sb.append("'%firstip%',");
sb.append("'%ip%',");
sb.append("%mute%,");
sb.append("%mutereason%,");
sb.append("TIME=%time%");
sb.append(") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ");
sb.append("FIRSTIP='%firstip%',");
sb.append("IP='%ip%',");
sb.append("MUTE=%mute%,");
sb.append("MUTEREASON=%mutereason%;");
```